# fluentbit writes to /var/log/messages

Tags: centos, fluent-bit

I'm running fluentbit (td-agent-bit) on a CentOS system in order to output all logs in a centralized system. Everytime fluentbit pushes a record to the remote location, it adds a record in /var/log/messages as well, leading up to a huge log filesize.

*Jul 21 08:48:53 hostname td-agent-bit: [2020/07/21 08:48:53] [ info] [out_azure] customer_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, HTTP status=200*

Any idea how can I stop a service (td-agent-bit) from writing to /var/log/messages? Couldn't find any configuration parameter (e.g. verbose) in fluentbit documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your log_level is "info" which includes a lot of messages of the pipeline. You can either decrease the log level inside the output section of the plugin to "error" only, e.g:

```
[OUTPUT]
    name      azure
    match     *
    log_level error
```

note: you can decrease the general log_level also in the main `[SERVICE]` section.

Comment: doesn't this mean that my "INFO" records will not be pushed to azure anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Even if log_level is set to error and there are lot of errors , then it is filling /var/log/messages which is in root volume and getting filled. Even though it is
log_level warn
log_file /mnt/fluent-bit.log

but most of the logs are getting ingested to /var/log/message which should not be. It should be always ingested to /mnt/fluent-bit.log

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The way to control fluent-bit logs not to flow to /var/log/message is to make changes in /etc/rsyslog.conf or define your configuration in /etc/rsyslogd/.conf to not pass logs from fluent-bit to /var/log/message or to allow to write log to /mnt/fluent-bit.log. There is no way to control this from fluent bit configuration. Need to be done from syslog configuration.